# Integrating Formotus Forms in iOS application

Tags: ios, ios7, infopath, infopath2010

I am developing an iOS application and want to use formotus form in it. We have SAP backend. I researched but could not find the solution. I only know how to create a form using Infopath and deploy them using Formotus console and then using formotus ios app, I can download that form on formotus app and can use it but I need to know a way so that I can use forms created using Infopath and formotus on my iOS app.
Thanks

Comment: This is much too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Please do some research first on the possible solutions, then come back when you have questions about specific problems.

Comment: @cosmo0 I have researched enough and could not find any solution and then I posted it on stack overflow. I edited the original question so that you can see that I created a form using infopath and deployed it using formotus console and then downloaded that app on the Formotus iOS app but I am unable to figure out a way to use it my own iOS app.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you've done (share some code), it's very difficult for us to help you. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how you can improve your question.

Comment: Formotus doesn't work that way.  You simply use the form in their app from the Formotus cloud.  They do have a custom URL that you can use to launch the Formotus app from yours  - http://support.formotus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203912459-How-to-use-links-to-open-Formotus-forms

Answer (score 0):

Paulw11 is correct. Also, Formotus is currently in process of expanding the options for opening our apps with syntax that will allow pre-filling form fields. So passing data from your own app to Formotus will soon be supported. To pass data the other direction would require you to implement a syntax of your own, e.g. MyApp://

I wonder, what are you unable to accomplish in Formotus alone that requires you to write another app?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to open and fill formotus forms in my own app. Now, I think I have to provide a link that will open the formotus client app to install the forms and submit the data to backend.